# How to give access to LUIS app to other users

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-collaborate) to give contribute access to other users. I have already migrated my LUIS resources to Azure. The people i give access to cannot see the apps I can under my account. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It should work, maybe some delay, please let the user refresh the portal.

Comment: refer to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6478 which is a similar issue. I would suggest you to double-check if you missed any steps. I would also ensure that the people are logging in to LUIS with the same email ids you provided them access for.

Comment: the thing is they are able to see some of the old apps i shared with them BEFORE migrating LUIS authoring to Azure. It is not working if I try with the new way.